# Qt 4.4: disabled widgets receiving mouse events

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qwidget

As the title suggests, is there a way for a disabled widget to receive mouse events?

I'm using `QWidget::setEnabled()` for changing the appearance of widgets but I still want to receive their mouse events. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you just want to change their appearance but still make them interactive, I suggest you use an alternative method than disabling the widget. A disabled widget by definition is meant to not be interactive.

Comment: Yeah, I felt this type of implementation was incorrect. However, it's part of a larger system so for the time being has to be carried on in this way :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an event filter on the widget in question. See [QObject::eventFilter()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#eventFilter). Your implementation might look something like this:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (ui->pushButton)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
        {
            qDebug() << "mouse button";
            return true;
        } else
        {
            return false;
        }
    } else
    {
        // pass the event on to the parent class
        return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
    }
}
```

This will work even if the button is disabled.

Comment: You forgot to mention that you need installEventFilter() first.

Comment: Thanks. That was covered by the information at the included link which broke since it was posted. The link works now and has that information.