# How to enable the disabled button

Tags: qt, button

I have a toolbutton which I want to disable when clicking on it (if it is enabled) and enable it when clicking on it (and it is disabled). The problem is that when clicking on it, I wrote the corresponding slot and it is disabling the button. So far it is working. But once disabled and you click on it, it does not jump to the slot, it is completely disabled forever. Am I using the wrong function or the wrong signal?

```
...
bool mEnable = true;

void Test::OnEnableButtonTriggered() {
  mEnable = !mEnable;
  ui.OnEnable->setEnabled(mEnable);
}
```

Comment: From a user's perspective, what is the benefit of being able to click a disabled button?

Comment: It is like a toggle button. Of course I can use different icons but I thought that disabling would work. Imagine you want to turn off the visualization by clicking on this button and later you want to turn it on. I saw this in many tools and wanted to try it myself

Comment: Should not a checkable toolbutton be the right button for that? When not pressed, your visualization is off, and the user needs to push down the button to turn visualization on (and the button stays down to visualize its state).

Comment: Exactly, this is what I found now, it suits best to my purposes. I only need to change the corresponding icons and it should work then.

Answer (score 3):

You can't trigger on a disabled button directly, but even if you can, you most probably shouldn't want to do that, as it's pretty irritating.

I'd suggest using a QCheckbox for what you're trying to achieve.

If you still want to use a disabled button, you might want to check out this post:

[Qt 4.4: disabled widgets receiving mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8467527/qt-4-4-disabled-widgets-receiving-mouse-events)

Comment: But this button is in my menutoolbar together with many other menu buttons. Using a Checkbox would be somehow strange and needs a label near to it

Comment: I think setCheckable could be the solution to my problem: it is pushed down when you click on it and remains pushed until you click on it again

Comment: In this case, switching the toolbar icon might be more intuitive.
However, you still can receive the events with an custom event filter.

Comment: Of course, didn't think of that obvious solution, setCheckable will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

`QPushButton`s can be set to be *checkable*. Using `isChecked()` you can read out the button's state. Connect to the `toggled()` slot to handle this state's change.

As Mark pointed out, it is uncommon to *disable* (or enable) an item by clicking on it. Disabling an item is a way of indicating that clicking on it will do nothing at all.

(I had not read the comments below Mark's answer before posting this one)